# What is the best way to validate Spreadsheet files (xls, xlsx and csv) in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on an application which processes spreadsheets in the following formats: **XLS, and XLSX**.
 I want to validate the file that the user selects to upload.I tried with all of them in my code, like:

```
$file=$request->file('file');
$rules = array('file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx');
$validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
if($validator->passes()) {
       //Code after validator pass

 }
```

but,above validator **mimes** is not working.